# Inapplicable: A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I don't understand why I am seeing the above error.  Yesterday, I was developing one project for deployment in a medium trust environment and ultimately had to strongly name the assembly.  That required that I strongly name a couple of underlying projects, which are used in several other assemblies.

Today I'm trying to run those other assemblies and I get the above error.  The kicker is that I removed the signing from the underlying libraries.  In the entire solution, none of my projects have Signing turned on.  I have cleaned the solution.  Restarted Visual Studio 2015.  But always, the above.

I've been playing around with the for a few hours and I can't find anything.  I have removed and added the project references to the once-signed projects within the assembly that this error is happening on.  I have added and removed other library references as well.  Still, the error.

Does anyone have any insight into why I keep getting this error at runtime or what I can do to overcome this obstacle?

Comment: In project root check for `licence` file, delete it and also delete it from `.csproj`  file, cant remember what xml tag would be there,search for licence.licx file

Comment: I found a licences.licx in one of the referenced projects of the project that I am debugging.  I removed it and the reference in the .csproj, but I still get the error.  That said, in examining the .csproj of the project I'm trying to debug I've noticed the following:  `
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>` I tried removing and changing the value to `false` but nothing worked.  Cleaned solution.  Still same error.

Comment: @jeromeyers Have you added any assembly to GAC in your installer project? then specific assembly has to be signed.

Comment: The error message does not have anything to do with code signing or license files.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot this.

Comment: The install project is a click once winforms application and I do not install into the GAC.

Comment: @HansPassant Using that fuslogvw tool (correctly??) I find the following:  Attempting to use native image C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web\c804bd515ae27aa9db4f0b59368bc2ea\System.Web.ni.dll.
Rejecting native image because it failed the security check. The assembly's permissions must have changed since the time it was ngenned, or it is running with a different security context.
Discarding native image.

Comment: Well, that's good advice but does not have anything to do with the problem either.  Change Fuslogvw's "Log categories" to Default.

Comment: @HansPassant Is it safe to say that the last binding even caught by the log viewer is the binding event that is causing the problem?

Comment: No.  You are getting more than one so you have a choice?  Well, that's not good.  Start from the top.

Comment: @HansPassant I had log all binds enabled.  Changing to log bind failures, I get nothing added to the list, but the same exception thrown at runtime.

Comment: @HansPassant The exception reports the error happening while loading project XYZ.  With log bind failures turned on, I get no logs.  With log all binding turned on, I get like 50 logs.  Several of them for project references - however, none of them for the project that is reporting in the exception to fail.  So, although the binding seems to fail, the log doesn't catch that failure?  Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure all nuget packages are at the same version across all projects in your solution. e.g. you dont want one project to reference NLog 4.0.0.0 and another project to reference NLog 4.1.0.0.  Then try reinstalling nuget packages with

Update-Package -reinstall

I had 3 3rd party assemblies that were referenced by my assembly A and only 2 were included in References by my assembly B which also referenced A.

The missing reference to the 3rd party assembly was added by the update package command, and the error went away.